# bokeh : slider through curves of dataset

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I have performed a parameter sweep in a simulation and want to plot the different curves in function of the parameters through which I want to go with sliders. 
I have done some bokeh before, this example should be pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to see why the plot disappears when I move my slider: 
Here the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from itertools import product

from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file,output_notebook, show, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

#synthetic data, 3 cos curves with different frequencies.
x=np.linspace(0,15,1000)
x=x.repeat(3).reshape(1000,3).T
y=np.zeros((3,np.shape(x)[1]))
y[0]=np.cos(x[0])
y[1]=np.cos(2*x[0])
y[2]=np.cos(3*x[0])


all_plots = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=y))
one_plot = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x[0],y=y[0]))

plot = figure(y_range=(-1,1), plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=one_plot, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(da=all_plots,dp=one_plot), code="""
    var dall = da.get('data');
    var dplot = dp.get('data');

    var idx = slider_plot.get('value');

    dplot['x'] = dall['x'][idx];
    dplot['y'] = dall['y'][idx];

    dp.trigger('change');
    da.trigger('change');

""")
slider_plot = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0, step=1,title="Freq", callback=callback)
callback.args["slider_plot"] = slider_plot



layout = column(widgetbox(slider_plot), plot)
show(layout)
```

As I move the slider, the plot simply disappears. I just can't find the mistake.

Cheers

EDIT: It seems like the error comes from handling multidimensional numpy arrays inside the ColumnDataSource.

```
dplot['x'] = dall['x'][idx];
dplot['y'] = dall['y'][idx];
```

These lines seem to cause the error. There is a way around this, by creating a datasource which indexes every row of the 2-D array,

```
source_x=ColumnDataSource(data=dict([(str(i),x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]))
source_y=ColumnDataSource(data=dict([(str(i),y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]))
```

by its position, so source_x.data['0'], would be the first line, etc. Then it works. However, for large parameter sweeps, creating the ColumnDataSource this way becomes prohibitively slow. Isn't there a way to access the entries of the 2D np.array in a clean way ?

Comment: Right, the callback is *JavaScript* code, that runs in the browser. There is no NumPy, and there are also no multidimensional arrays, in JavaScript or in the browser. In particular, there is no slicing, so `dall['x'][idx]` doesn't pull out a 1-d slice. It just pulls out the single number at `idx` in the one big 1d array that JS sees. But BokehJS is expecting an array, not a number, and this is probably the proximate cause of the problem. Your best bet is to use `idx` and the stride to assemble the slice you need using JavaScript in the callback.

Comment: Hi, I ended up implementing your solution. Indeed, by looking at the 2D array as a stacked 1D array, one needs to simply stride through it as idx*x.length : (idx+1):x.length

Comment: If you self-answer the question I am happy to vote it up.